Magento 2 Backend admin config system error
I have found an issue on Magento 2.4.7 only in developer mode.
error:
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Magento_MediaStorage::system/config/system/storage/media/synchronize.phtml' in module: 'Magento_MediaStorage' block's name: 'system\config\system\storage\media\synchronize_0'

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Magento_MediaStorage::system/config/system/storage/media/synchronize.phtml' in module: 'Magento_MediaStorage' block's name: 'system\config\system\storage\media\synchronize_0'

I know everything in developer mode is sync linked but I can't see this .phtml in the location.
Anyone have any idea why this only happened in developer?

I have already installed the same version in my localhost and not found such issue and I also checked in Magento 2.4.7 and found that file is already existing,
On below location you will found file is present or not
vendor\magento\module-media-storage\view\adminhtml\templates\system\config\system\storage\media\synchronize.phtml
Thank You!
